# Service created each time I'm binding to it - but I want a singleton service

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a service that should be a singleton - I need one of it for the entire application.

I tried to implement this using a START_STICKY flag, but each time I bind to the service from an activity its onCreate is called and the activity is stopped, the service's onDestroy is called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Class ApplicationClass Extends Application and create getter and setter method for the service class object from that you can run service through out the application when application is removed than service will destroy otherwise it will run.

Comment: you mean I should bind the service to the application object instead of the activity object?

Comment: see also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables

Comment: Yes Exactly, thats what I mean.